# How do I make the whole of a DNN 7 Container/HTML Module a link?

Tags: dotnetnuke, containers

I have a DNN skin that has some nice containers.  I can drop an HTML module onto the page and apply the container to it.  I can put a link in the content of the HTML Module, but what I would really like to do is make the whole container/module area a link to another page - in effect as if it were a great big button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course as soon as I posted the question I found a way, but would still be interested to know if this is the "right" way or even a "good" way.

My solution was to take a copy of the container .ascx and add an "onlick" to the outer DIV, which in turn uses JQuery to locate the first  tag and to navigate to the href.

```
    <div class="Container-1 Container-1-color1" 
     onclick="window.location.href = $('a:first',this).attr('href')">
```

*Note: Use `window.location.href`, not JQuery `.click()` or `.trigger('click')` as this creates an infinite loop.*

I then added some CSS to show that an action was available when the mouse was over the container:

```
.Container-1:hover 
{
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: That should work fine.  Note that jQuery (or JavaScript in general) cannot trigger the native click action of a link, so using `location` is required.  I'd suggest moving this script into an external file, rather than using `onclick`.  Something like `jQuery(function ($) { $('.Container-1').on('click', function () { window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href'); }); });`

Comment: Thanks @bdukes - I like the idea of moving the code to an external file and leaving the (3rd party) skin unchanged. Did you miss off the ".href" from the "window.location"?

Comment: When you set `location`, it's the same as setting its `href` property.  Either way works fine

Comment: How would I refactor this for a DNN module. I would like to link just the "Learn More" text in the CMS and then have the entire colored box area be clickable/linked using that link. Example: http://bit.ly/20ZsQA0 - If I click the box it successfully has a link but it does not go to the correct href.
code---
$('.L3BoxNavHolder li').on('click', function () { 
        window.location = $('.L3BoxNavHolder li a:first', this).attr('href'); 
    });
---/code